# Combinatorial argument for the number of pairs whose sum is less than or equal to k

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

**Example**: How many pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x+y <= k$, where `x` `y` and `k` are integers and $x,y>=0, k > 0$.

My solution:

If we fix `x` then we can choose `y` in $(k - x + 1)$ ways (i.e. $y = 0,1,2,3 .... (k-x)$).

Therefore, the final answer can be calculated as follows:

$\begin{align*} 
&=\sum_{x = 0}^{k}\left ( k - x + 1 \right ) \\
&=\sum_{p = 1}^{k+1}\left ( p \right ) \qquad \left [ \text{ replacing k - x + 1 with p} \right ] \\
&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}
\end{align*}$

It seems that the final answer is equals to ${k+2\choose 2}\qquad$ (or choosing `2` out of `k+2` distinct objects).

**Question**: What can be the (possible) combinatorial argument for this answer ${k+2\choose 2}$ w.r.t to the counting of $(x,y)$ pairs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $k$ items and $2$ 'dividers'.  Arrange them in any order you wish. There are ${k+2}\choose{2}$ ways to do this.

The number of items (perhaps $0$) to the left of the first divider is your first addend; and the number of items between the two dividers is your second addend.

For example, with $k = 5$, you could have $|**|***$ corresponding to $0+2$.  Or you could have $*|****|$ corresponding to $1+4$.